# Firebase auth database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

var config = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    databaseURL: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
});

firebase.database().ref('/Settings').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val().adminID);
});
```

I wrote this code to read some data from database, but it give me an error. It say that I'm not authenticated, how ca i fix it?

Comment: Did you define rules in your firebase databse?

Comment: did you authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that javascript is Asynchronous, so you will log with email and password but maybe you won't be already logged for the query. So if you have rules (it can fail)  :

```
{
 "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

Try this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( (data) => 
  {    
    // here your query
  firebase.database().ref('/Settings').once('value').then(function(snapshot) 
  {
      console.log(snapshot.val().adminID);
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Open firebase database and go to rules section and add rules there.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is this rules

Comment: This won't work because he is not querying only when he is logged. (Async ...)